# Retrieve data from sql column by splitting one column into two

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID  DepID   Status
------------------
000 54  0
000 12  1
141 14  0
141 56  1
000 12  0
000 89  1
```

I have the above table in which I have the `depID`. The following is the output I need:

```
ID  DepOld  DepNew
-------------------
000 54        12
141 14        56
000 12        89
```

Status of 0 means its old and 1 means new. How do I get the above output, considering it's in one table?

I can't use the `IN` clause.

I tried the following

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   Max(CASE
          WHEN Status = 0 THEN DepID
       END) DepOld,
   Max(CASE
          WHEN Status = 1 THEN DepID
       END) DepNew
FROM   
   tablename
GROUP BY 
   ID
```

but this the output I get

```
Id   DepOld  DepNew
--------------------
000  54      54
000  12      NULL
141  14      14
141  56      Null
```

if i pass depID=54 then this output is what i want

ID DepOld    DepNew

---

```
000  54      12
```

Comment: Full self-join with additional conditions on status field should work.

Comment: Check your data. Shall the IDs in row 1,2 and 5,6 be the same i.e. 000 ? Same with the suggested outcome.

Comment: no it shouldnt be the same, the ids are not unique

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when status = 0 then DepID end) as DepOld,
       max(case when status = 1 then DepID end) as DepNew
from table t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Case statement` and `Max aggragate` you can get the result.

```
CREATE TABLE #fast
  (
     ID     VARCHAR(100),
     DepID  INT,
     Status INT
  )

INSERT INTO #fast
VALUES     ( '000',54,0),
            ('000',12,1),
            ('141',14,0),
            ('141',56,1),
            ('000',12,0),
            ('000',89,1)


SELECT ID,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Status = 0 THEN DepID
           END) DepOld,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Status = 1 THEN DepID
           END) DepNew
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY ID
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion now but its giving me inconsistent information

Comment: @john What is the datatype of ID column

Comment: i will be passing in the department id ,so if i pass in the depID of 54 it must get the list for only that IDs

Comment: its an integer datatype

Comment: @john You cannot store 000 in int datatype. It will be converted to 0. I am not getting the same answer as yours i will update my answer with insert statement.

Comment: @john - when you pass deptid=54 then what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll only ever have two rows per ID, one with Status = 0 and the other with Status = 1, you could join the table to itself based on the `ID` column so you have both the old and new Department IDs available in a single row:

```
SELECT old.ID, old.DepID AS DepOld, new.DepID AS DepNew
FROM your_table old
INNER JOIN your_table new ON old.ID = new.ID AND new.Status = 1
WHERE old.Status = 0
```

Comment: in the select statement there is only one coloumn named DepID, theres no old.DepID AS DepOld, new.DepID AS DepNew to select from